# Keil compiler v5 to v.6

Tags: c, clang, armcc

I'm forced to switch from ARMCC v5 to CLANG(v.6). Here is the problem.
I have some struct that includes a pointer to the function which gets as a parameter pointer to the same structure.
So I do

```
struct _some_struct_s;
typedef void (*callback_f)(struct _some_struct *p);
 
typedef struct {
  callback_f fn;
  int        x; 
} some_type_s;

// init function
void init_some_struct (some_struct *p, callback_f f) {
  p->fn = f;
  p->x = 0;
}
```

In another file I'm writing the callback() and calling init_some_struct()

```
some_type_s  my_struc;
void callback (some_type_s *p) {
  p->x++;
}
init_some_struct (&my_struc, callback);
```

I had no issues with compiler 5 but a warning with version 6.

---

```
warning: incompatible function pointer types passing 'void (some_struct_s *)' to parameter of type 'callback_f' (aka 'void (*)(struct _some_struct_s *)') [-Wincompatible-function-pointer-types]
```

What can I do to avoid having this warning?

What can I do to avoid having this warning?

Comment: `void callback (&some_type_s *p) {
  p->x++;
}` is not ordinary C code; `void callback` introduces a declaration, but `&some_type_s *p` is not a declaration, because the `&` does not belong there. Is that an error (e.g., something copied and pasted wrong) posting the question? Some Keil feature? Did you not get a compiler message for that? Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: In the second line of the first code sequence, `struct _some_struct *p` looks like a typo that should have been `struct _some_struct_s *p`. In that `typedef`, the return type of the function is missing. You use `some_struct` later, but there is no declaration for `some_struct`.

Comment: You need to copy and paste _from the originally working code_ that you "did not have any issues with". Not randomly type stuff into the question. First it's `some_type_s`, then `some_struct`? And `some_struct` is different from `_some_struct`?

Comment: There is no return type specified for the function.  Presumably, that defaults to `int`, but it was sloppy style in C90 and not strictly legal in C99 or later.

Comment: &Eric Postpischil: 
 1. You're correct. I removed --&--. Sorry, typo.
2. I corrected this line as well, another typo
4. After correcting #2 not an issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@ John Bollinger Thank you. I resolved my issue.

```
typedef struct _some_struct_s {
...
}some_struct_s;
```

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

1. `typedef (*callback_f)(struct _some_struct *p);` - you alias the type as function of pointer which returns `int`.

It should be `typedef void (*callback_f)(struct some_struct *p);`

2. ```
   typedef struct {
        callback_f *fn;
   ```

   `fn` is a pointer to pointer to function. It should be `callback_f fn;`

```
typedef struct some_struct _some_struct_s;
typedef void callback_f(struct _some_struct *p);
 
typedef struct some_struct{
  callback_f *fn;
  int        x; 
} some_struct_s;

// init function
void init_some_struct (some_struct *p, callback_f *f) {
  p->fn = f;
  p->x = 0;
}
```

Comment: @qulpr:I corrected the typos please see my comments above

Comment: I'm sorry for the typos. My question was directed towards the compiler warning. To avoid this warning I have to  write the second line in the second code segment as
void callback (struct _some_type_s *p) 
But I don't like that

Comment: it is because you have a double pointer in your struct as I wrote it

Comment: It was a typo, which was fixed. This warning has a different nature.

Comment: @Submin if you do not put even a minimum effort into your question, like making typos, posting code which does not compile etc you show no respect to people who try to help you for free in their free time.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to a function pointer of type `callback_f` has type `struct _some_struct *`, while the function `callback` takes an argument of type `some_type_s *` where `some_type_s` is an alias for an anonymous struct type.  These are not the same.

Presumably these should be the same, so you need to give that anonymous struct a tag:

```
typedef struct _some_struct {
  callback_f *fn;
  int        x; 
} some_type_s;
```

Comment: Thank you. 
The structure of type some_type_s includes a pointer to the function which takes a pointer to the structure of the same type as a parameter. This is why struct _some_type_s was declared. It is just a structure, not a type in terms of C( correct me if it's not). 
Then the typedef callback_f was defined, and lastly, the typed of structure some_type_s. 
If you can suggest any other order - let me know.
Still, is there any other way to avoid the given warning?

Comment: @Submin, when you say "*It is just a structure, not a type*", I'm inclined to think that you have a misunderstanding.  Structure types are types. On the other hand, `typedef` declarations do not define types -- rather, they define *aliases* for types.  Typedefs are strictly syntactic sugar, but they are woefully easy to use in ways that tend to confuse more than they clarify.

Comment: In K&R C, a structure is not inherently a type on its own. However, you can make it behave like one using the typedef keyword.
In K&R C, when you define a structure, you create a new composite data type that groups together different variables (fields) under a single name.
Nowadays (C99) you're probably correct.

Comment: @Submin, structure types have been types since at least the 1st edition of K&R's *The C Programming Language* in 1978.  From some time before that, `typedef` serves only to define a new *name* for an existing type.  You can leverage that to avoid writing type names containing the `struct` keyword, and it can facilitate (re)using tagless structure types, but if you don't *have* a type then you cannot write a well formed typedef declaration in the first place.  I'm not inclined to think that typedef *ever* served any other purpose, and I've never heard such a claim before.

Comment: @John Bollinger: I don't want to get into a discussion of typedef. I just asked ChatGPT4 and it confirmed what I was saying, so let's agree to disagree, as I mentioned before it's a matter of preferences

Comment: @Submin, `typedef` is not the point, inasmuch as it can be separated from structure types.  But structure types *are* the point, and you have some misunderstandings in that area, not all of them associated with `typedef`.  I suspect that's why you do not recognize that your question has already been answered.  You came here hoping to find someone who knows something that you do not.  I assure you that ChatGPT is not that in any sense, but perhaps you could entertain the possibility that you found some people who *are* that.

Answer (score 0):

The code presented is not internally consistent.  I'm having trouble believing that any compiler accepted it, but I'm uncertain whether that's because you've omitted other relevant pieces or because even with your corrections it still doesn't match the code that your old compiler accepted.

This is what I think you're looking for, annotated in code comments:

```
// Forward declaration of type struct some_struct_s
// This is needed because this type is self referential via
// the type of the callback function.
struct some_struct_s;

// "callback_f" declared as an alias for type void (*)(struct some_struct_s *p)
typedef void (*callback_f)(struct some_struct_s *p);
 
// Definition of type struct some_struct_s
// I have removed the typedef part because the name of the typedef alias was confusing
// (probably wrong), and because it is unneeded.
struct some_struct_s {
    callback_f fn;
    int        x; 
};

// But if you really want the typedef, then you can declare it separately:
typedef struct some_struct_s some_struct;

// This is how to declare the function without relying on alias "some_struct"
void init_some_struct (struct some_struct_s *p, callback_f f) {
    p->fn = f;
    p->x = 0;
}
```

```
// ...

// C does not support nested functions, so this should be at file scope, outside
// any function
void callback(struct some_struct_s *p) {
    p->x++;
}

// ...
// But function _calls_ must appear only inside function bodies, so for example:
void some_other_function(void) {
    // ...
    struct some_struct_s my_struc;
    init_some_struct(&my_struc, callback);
    // ...
}
```

#### Addendum: the same thing, a different style

Since you seem highly motivated to use a different style, and do not recognize how to convert the above, here is a version that focuses using a `typedef` alias for your structure type:

```
// Forward declaration of type struct some_struct_s
// This is needed because this type is self referential via
// the type of the callback function.
// The name of the type being declared is "struct some_struct_s", and the tag is
// essential for what you're trying to do.
struct some_struct_s;

// This typedef could be combined  with the previous declaration, if you prefer.
// Separating it emphasizes the separate significance of the typedef
// and forward declaration.
// Declaring it here allows it to be used in all the subsequent declarations.
typedef struct some_struct_s some_struct;

// "callback_f" declared as an alias for type "void (*)(some_struct *p)"
typedef void (*callback_f)(some_struct *p);
 
// Definition of type struct some_struct_s
// The tag is essential here.  It's what allows other declarations
// to refer to this structure type.
struct some_struct_s {
    callback_f fn;
    int        x; 
};

void init_some_struct (some_struct *p, callback_f f) {
    p->fn = f;
    p->x = 0;
}
```

```
// ...

// C does not support nested functions, so this should be at file scope, outside
// any function
void callback(some_struct *p) {
    p->x++;
}

// ...
// But function _calls_ must appear only inside function bodies, so for example:
void some_other_function(void) {
    // ...
    some_struct my_struc;
    init_some_struct(&my_struc, callback);
    // ...
}
```

Essentials:

- the name of the structure type involved there is `struct some_sruct_s`, formed from the `struct` keyword and the structure tag.  In C, the tag is *not* a name for the type by itself, but that's different in C++.
- You can choose whatever tag you like for the structure type, including the `typedef` name, but **you cannot omit the tag altogether.**  That's what allows the type to be referenced before its declaration is complete, including inside its own declaration.  Every variation on self reference requires that.
- the `typedef` declaration declares `some_struct` as an alias for type `struct some_struct_s`.  Anywhere the typedef is in scope, the two names for the type can be used interchangeably.  (The typedef's scope is necessarily a subset of the structure type's scope).

Comment: Your comments are correct. I'm not sure about the following: "// I have removed the typedef part because the name of the typedef alias was confusing (probably wrong), and because it is unneeded."
For the last 30+ years, I've always used in C for the following :
typedef struct {
} some_struct_s; // defining my new type
In this case, because _some_struct_s has been already defined, it looks :
typedef _some_struct_s {
} some_struct_s;
It is a matter of personal preferences, but is not too relevant to my question: is there another way to avoid the given warning, which I didn't have with v.5

Comment: @Submin, if you want to use anonymous structure types with `typedef`ed aliases then you certainly can do, at least wherever you don't need self-referential structure types.  You can of course use `typedef`ed aliases for tagged structure types, too.  However, the code presented in the question contains a forward declaration of and a references to type `struct _some_struct`, but no definition of that type.  And there is also a type `some_struct` referenced but never defined.  And a typedef for `some_struct_s`, separate from all of the above.

Comment: @Submin, I have presented valid C code for what you appear to want to do that is consistent with every version of standard C and most pre-standard implementations back to at least the publication of the 1st edition of K&R.  If you wanted to refer to the structure type via name `some_struct` instead of the name `struct some_struct_s` then you could make that substitution any and everywhere that the typedef declaration is in scope.

Comment: @Submin, I'm inclined to guess that your real code makes use of pointers to an undefined structure type (which is allowed), and that you are matching those with pointers to a different structure type (which is wrong).  Your compiler might have accepted such code without complaint, but its behavior was never defined by any published version of C.  This answer shows how to fix that.

Comment: @ John Bollinger. I'm positive that you figured out that the actual code is an ISR handler. All I wanted was to get rid of the warning (I copied and pasted it into my first post). I posted how did I do that but I don't like it.

Comment: @Submin, I have added an alternative version that you might prefer, as it focuses on using a `typedef`ed name for the structure type involved.  I think that the key point eluding you may be that you *must* declare the structure type with a tag in order for any variation on self-reference to conform to (any version of) the C language.